# JSF 2.0 How to use Apache Myfaces with Glassfish V3

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I am trying to use Myfaces with Glassfish but its not working. I have made sure myfaces-api and myfaces-impl are the JSF runtimes deployed with my application but Glassfish still runs the application with the mojarra version.

I was thinking classes in the lib folder supercede those in the application sever.

If I remove the jsf-api and jsf-impl from the modules folder in glassfish, I get a an error on startup with some OSGI noise.

What is the recommeded way of using myfaces for ann application deployed with glassfish?

Comment: [Sigh. Some better Google-fu is required.](http://old.nabble.com/MyFaces-on-Glassfish-3-td31763259.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Google is a big place so your search results will return something different from mine, plus a member of the JSF Expert group even didn't know! Check the one who asked the question. So please don't sigh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

Solved by declaring this in glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="false"/>
  <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following in the sun-web.xml

```
<sun-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false"/>
    <property name="useMyFaces" value="true"/>
</sun-web-app>
```